# Why is the reverse zone name appended to the returned domain names in reverse DNS lookup?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, nslookup

Not sure if I missed something when I set up the PTR records for the hostnames on FreeIPAv4. We use FreeIPAv4 to manage the identity and policy on the LAN.

When I conducted the reverse DNS lookup against the reverse zone **2.10.10.in-addr.arpa**, some returned domain names were appended with the reverse zone name, while others were not.

Here are two examples. **10.10.2.104** returned the hostname correctly, while **10.10.2.21** returned the hostname appended with the reverse zone name.

```
[root@rep02.ipa.example.com ~]# nslookup
> nginx02.prd.example.com
Server:     10.10.4.3
Address:    10.10.4.3#53

Name:   nginx02.prd.example.com
Address: 10.10.2.21
> 10.10.2.21
21.2.10.10.in-addr.arpa name = nginx02.prd.example.com.2.10.10.in-addr.arpa.
```

```
> tomcat.sbx.example.com
Server:     10.10.4.3
Address:    10.10.4.3#53

Name:   tomcat.sbx.example.com
Address: 10.10.2.104
> 10.10.2.104
104.2.10.10.in-addr.arpa    name = tomcat.sbx.example.com.
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I tried several other tools, like **dig** and **host**, but I got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the trailing dot in the ptr record value in the bind zone file.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! what a shame!

Comment: thank you very much.